# Ruby: How can I search all file and ignore some unwanted?

Tags: ruby

I got a problem on Ruby directory searching. I want to implment sth like gitignore file.
When some file are listed in an ignore file, it will not be searched.

For example
here is a list of directory, if i want to ignore /bar ( and all its sub files)

```
/bar    (directory)
/bar/a.txt
/bar/b.txt
/foo
/foo/c.txt
/foo/d.txt
```

If I use 
`Dir["/**/*"]`
every file will be searched.
how can i just search through foo directory only?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir["/**/*"].reject{|f|f["/bar/"]}.each do |file|
  puts file
end
=>
/foo
/foo/c.txt
/foo/d.txt
```

In case you have multiple subs to filter out use Regexp.union, eg all my google drive files without the subs \docs and \ruby

```
pattern = Regexp.union("C:/Users/peter/Google Drive/ruby", "C:/Users/peter/Google Drive/docs")
Dir["C:/Users/peter/Google Drive/**/**"].reject{|f|f[pattern]}.each do |file|
  p file
end
```